# Notice: Undefined variable: row when PDO returns no data

Tags: php

I have this code -

```
$previous_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-14 days"));

$conn = testdb_connect ();

        $getfamilydate= get_family_date ($previous_date);

        if (! $row)
        {
        echo "No testcase being executed in the selected duration";
        } else { while($row = $getfamilydate->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            { 
            foreach($row as $key) 
                {
                    $twoWeekfamily[] = $key;
                }           
            }
        }
```

Here I am trying to check wether the query returns any result for the specified duration(previous date), and if not it should display the msg else return the array.

I have duration like -

1day, 2ay, 1week, 2 week.. etc., and I am using the same code for all the duration. This logic works fine for 1day, i.e, if no data than it shows the msg but for all others if query returns no data than it throws **Undefined variable: row** notice.

What is wrong with the logic here ?

Comment: You're testing for something that isn't hasn't been set yet: ` if (! $row)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like -

```
while($row = $getfamilydate->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        { 
        foreach($row as $key) 
            {
                $twoWeekfamily[] = $key;
            }           
        }
 if(empty( $twoWeekfamily))
 {
echo "No testcase being executed in the selected duration";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you code like below

```
if (! $getfamilydate){
    echo "No testcase being executed in the selected duration";
}
else {
     $count = $getfamilydate->rowCount();
     if($count > 0){
         while($row = $getfamilydate->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
         { 

              var_dump($row);

         }
     }
    else{
        echo "No rows found";
    }
}
```

In your code you are checking $row before setting the values to the $row

Comment: in this case no msg is printed!

Comment: try putting a echo inside the else to check whether it reaches the else. and why do you use a foreach inside the while. check my new update.

Comment: i am using foreach to save the output in array.

Comment: try my update to check weather you are getting up to the inside of the while first. Then try putting your for loop

Comment: it is going in the else part but not showing any output.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$getfamilydate->rowCount()){
    echo "No testcase being executed in the selected duration";
}else { while($row = $getfamilydate->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        { 
            foreach($row as $key) 
            {
                $twoWeekfamily[] = $key;
            }           
        }}
```

Use `$getfamilydate->rowCount()` instead of `$row` in `if` statement.